# Is it mandatory to adhere to the Holo themes when designing a new android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-experience

I am a UX designer and new the android app marketplace.

I am designing an app for android 4. and above and need to know if I have total free reign in terms of UI design or is it mandatory to stick to the Holo themes and the Action bar, tabs, etc.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

Hi there and welcome to the Android world. Of course you can just make your own Design prinziples. But the user can easily use your App when you keep some Design principles in your App so the user knows how to navigate through your App. See following [Link](http://developer.android.com/design/style/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not mandatory to follow the design guidelines. In fact, as the name itself suggests, those are guidelines. Not rules. You are free to follow them or not.

However, it is important to make the app as intuitive as possible. By following the design guidelines you will make your app as native as build-in applications. This will eliminate possible user confusions or need to *teach* the users how to use your app.

As an example, see a case study by Pocket: [Tiny Impacts: The Case of the Accidental Archive](http://getpocket.com/blog/2013/10/tiny-impacts-the-case-of-the-accidental-archive/) (emphasis is mine)

> Looking at people who opened an article in Pocket for the first time, and were presented with this toolbar, the Up Button change **increased the likelihood they would continue using Pocket from this point onwards by 23%**! That is a lot of frustration eliminated for a minor change.

But if one comes up with simpler and better clarity that does not match with the given guidelines, I believe, one should stick with those of her design principles.